# how to implement moving average in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I want to implement moving average in hightchart.
Is there any option in highchart for this.

Like: I have series `10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70`

and here the moving average would be `2`.

Then second series will generate on average values of series `1`

like: `15, 35, 105` (taking average of each two datapoints)

And embedding this moving average series of `series1` on the same chart.

Answer (score 6):

you can calculate the moving average and add it like this:

```
$('#buttonAddSeries').click(function() {
    var series = chart.series[0];
    var data = [];
    var period = 2;
    var sumForAverage = 0;
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<series.data.length;i++) {
        sumForAverage += series.data[i].y;
        if(i<period) {
            data.push(null);
        } else {
            sumForAverage -= series.data[i-period].y;
            data.push([series.data[i].x, sumForAverage/period]);
        }
    }
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'Moving Average',
        data: data
    });
});
```

You can use any number of points as the period, not only 2.

Answer (score 4):

No, currently HighCharts does not do any data analysis like this. You would need to generate your own moving average and create that as its own series or plotLine/plotBand.

Answer (score 4):

These days there is a plugin for Highcharts with which you can add a SMA (Simple Moving Average).

See: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/16/technical-indicators

Answer (score 4):

Moving averages are supported using the technical indicators plug-in found [here](https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/16/technical-indicators)

Here is a link to the [JavaScript source](https://rawgit.com/laff/technical-indicators/master/technical-indicators.src.js) that you'll need to include:

It is implemented by adding another series to the chart of type: 'trendline', algorithm: 'SMA' that refers to the relevant data series by id:

```
series : [
{
  name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
  type : 'line',
  id: 'primary',
  data : [100,101,105,107,104,105,106,104,...]
}, {
  name: '15-day SMA',
  linkedTo: 'primary',
  showInLegend: true,
  type: 'trendline',
  algorithm: 'SMA',
  periods: 15
}]
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laff/WaEBc/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more efficient than a for loop:

```
$('#buttonAddSeries').click(function() {

    var series = chart.get('seriesId')
    var yData = series.processedYData
    var xData = series.processedXData
    var data = [];
    var period = 3;
    
    /* sumForAverage initialised to sum of yData indexed between 0 and period */
    var sumForAverage = yData.slice(0, period).reduce(function(prev, cur) {
        return prev + cur;
    });
    
    /* Subset yData from period to end. */
    yDataWindow = yData.slice(period, yData.length)
    
    /* At each point add the new value and subtract yData[currentIndex]. */
    yDataWindow.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) {
        /* push each iteration to data */
        data.push([xData[currentIndex + period], previousValue/period])
        return previousValue + currentValue - yData[currentIndex]
      /* sumForAverage is passed as starting value */
    }, sumForAverage)
    
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'Moving Average',
        data: data
    });
});
```

Example: [JS Fiddle with data](https://jsfiddle.net/8zso920k/3/)